# Combine Result of flatten Function

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

How can I combine the result of a flatten function in Dataweave? I have the following payload:

```
[
  {
    "a": "hello"
  },
  {
    "b": "please"
  },
  {
    "c": "help"
  },
  {
    "d": "me!"
  }
]
```

and I want it to be like this:

```
[
  {
    "a": "hello",
    "b": "please",
    "c": "help",
    "d": "me!"
  }
]
```

I'm unable to figure out how to resolve this.

Comment: That the input is the result of flatten() seems to not be relevant to the question. It could have come from some other operation. You should instead ask how to combine a list of objects into a single object.

Comment: @aled it seems confusedstudent really got confused regarding how to post an appropriate question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Object destructor](https://www.prostdev.com/post/combining-objects-concatenation-in-dw-2-0)

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
[{(payload)}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[payload reduce ((item, acc = {}) -> acc ++ item)]
```